# how to start angular router after base href without changing assets address

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an angular app I want to render my app from `/en/myapp/` URL I find a solution with base href I can solve it, however, it raises a bigger problem it also changes assets URL, for example, `/main.css` is changed to `/en/myapp/main.css` and I don't want that and if I set base href to `/` angular router service consider /en/myapp as internal angular routes which is't and render 404 component so how to start my angular app form specific route without any change in assets files URL?

**UPDATE**

My server route is not fixed it is something like this `/en/:username`
and in this route, I render angular index page so I can't use deploy-url option in angular-cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `--deploy-url` option.

`ng build --base-href /en/myapp --deploy-url /`

Comment: the only problem with that solution is that my server route isn't fixed actually it is something like this /en/:username and in this route, I render angular index page.Sorry I think this should  be mentioned in the question statement

Comment: How does your current solution work then? How do you change base href

Comment: I change it dynamically in index.html something like this
`‍‍`‍‍`‍‍
  <base href="/" id="baseHref">
  <script>
    (function () {
      document.getElementById('baseHref').href = '/en/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    })();
  </script>
``‍‍`‍‍

Comment: Ok. Is your project still an angular cli project ? If yes, can you only specify deploy-url?

Comment: yes that's worked thanks but one problem it doesn't effect on assets folder path
/en/assets/images/ and it has redundant /en/ at first

Comment: So that works for css but not for other assets? How do you reference you assets ? E.g. for images

Comment: here is an example of one image
assets/images/profilepic/1f0f84d0-8d6a-11e7-a1c0-6bc2140cf8b9.jpg
but the browser request this
/en/assets/images/profilepic/1f0f84d0-8d6a-11e7-a1c0-6bc2140cf8b9.jpg 
I fetch this URL from the server after app loaded and put it in my view with angular I don't know if this related or not
here is screenshot of my browser https://imgur.com/a/zu65L

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169052/discussion-between-daniel-v-and-david).

Comment: Don't you just need to specify the asset with leading slash? `/assets/images...`

Comment: yes you were right thanks so much for your answer it helped me a lot